# Android studio Gradle sync failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hi (I'm new to this so you'll have to forgive me)

I'm trying to fix a grade sync issue. My project synced fine before i added this line to my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0'
```

After I removed it I got the following error in the grade build window:
[image]

If I attempt to click on "Install Repsoitory and sync project" or "open file" nothing happens.

I've messed around with the version numbers for the dependencies as some research suggested this may be the cause. I've also tried removing various dependancies to see if that helps and the message only goes away if i remove all dependancies beginning with `com.android.support.

Obviously the app won't compile now so I don't know where to go from here.

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now and could do with some help pointing in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alexwoohouse.heartofengland"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.1.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        // exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.0'


}
```

[UPDATE] Error after performing `./gradlew clean build` command.

```
    Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.2/g
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.1.2/build
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.1.2/lint-25.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.1.2/gr
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.1.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.pom       
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.3/asm-parent-5.0
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.pom               
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/5.2.1/progu
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-parent/5.2.1/progu
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.4.2015022621
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.4.201502262
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr/3.5.2/antlr-3.5.2.pom     
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.5.2/antlr-master-3
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/9/oss-parent-9.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/2.1.2
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/2.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/25.1.2/sdklib-25.1
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/25.1.2/sdk-com
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.1.2/common-25.1
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/25.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/25.1.2/ddmlib
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.10.0/jack
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.10.0/jill
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.p
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/25.1.2/l
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/25.1.2/annota
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava-parent/17.0/guava-pa
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.1.2/b
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/4.5/antlr4-4.5.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4-master/4.5/antl
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.po
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/25/common
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom          
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversal
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/5.2.1/proguar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-a
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.1/asm-parent-5.0
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5.2/antlr-runtime
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.8/ST4-4.0.8.pom         
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/2
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/25.1.2/dvlib-25.1.2
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/repository/25.1.2/reposit
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/c
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/33/common
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom        
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-cl
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/4.1.1/pro
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/http
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-cl
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom   
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/25.1.2/lint
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.3/asm-analysis
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4-runtime/4.5/ant
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4-annotations/4.5
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-1
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/http
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-co
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commo
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom          
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-cod
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/common
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-as
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/abego/treelayout/org.abego.treelayout.c
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.2/g
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder/2.1.2/build
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/25.1.2/lint-25.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/2.1.2/gr
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compilerCommon/2.1.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.3/asm-5.0.3.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.3/asm-commons-5
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/5.2.1/progu
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.4.2015022621
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr/3.5.2/antlr-3.5.2.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/2.1.2
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/2.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdklib/25.1.2/sdklib-25.1
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/sdk-common/25.1.2/sdk-com
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.1.2/common-25.1
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/25.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/25.1.2/ddmlib
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jack/jack-api/0.10.0/jack
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/jill/jill-api/0.10.0/jill
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.3/asm-tree-5.0.3.j
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/25.1.2/l
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.4.2/ecj
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/annotations/25.1.2/annota
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/2.1.2/b
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/4.5/antlr4-4.5.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.ja
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversal
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/5.2.1/proguar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-a
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5.2/antlr-runtime
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.8/ST4-4.0.8.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/2
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/dvlib/25.1.2/dvlib-25.1.2
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/repository/25.1.2/reposit
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/c
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/http
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/25.1.2/lint
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.3/asm-analysis
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4-runtime/4.5/ant
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4-annotations/4.5
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-1
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/http
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commo
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-cod
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-as
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/abego/treelayout/org.abego.treelayout.c
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms o
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:          
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:transition:25.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/transition/25.0.0/trans
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/transition/25.0.0/trans
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
     Required by:           
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:25.0.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:preference-v14:25.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/preference-v14/25.3.0/p
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/preference-v14/25.3.0/p
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
     Required by:           
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:25.3.0.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/25
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/25
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
     Required by:           
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-utils/25.3
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-utils/25.3
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
     Required by:           
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/25.3.0/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/25.3.0/
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
     Required by:           
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:25.0.0 > co
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2reposit
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
         file:/C:/Users/delta/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2reposito
     Required by:           
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.
         HeartOfEngland:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.

* Try:                      
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug

BUILD FAILED                

Total time: 46.802 secs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out somewhere along the line, parts of my installation of the android support respiratory seem to have been corrupted/deleted.

I managed to fix the issue by going into the standalone android SDK manager, deleted the Android Support Respiratory under the 'extras' section and installed it again.

Once I had done that the grade build seemed to compile just fine.